# Send data to MySQL and display the updated DB (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am new to AJAX and I've been working all day on a project that I can't get to work. By the way, english is not my first language so sorry in advance !

Basics of the project :
-a simple page with a section to enter a message and a section that display all the message already entered by users
-the user type his text in a textarea and click on a button to submit his message
-the new message is sent to the database and the "comment section" is updated with the new message (AJAX)

Basically it should work like the Youtube comment system.

So far, with Javascript, PHP, AJAX, jQuery and Json, this is what I've been able to get done by myself:
-When the user click on the button, the message is successfully sent to the database.
-I can display all the existing message of the database inside a "div" of my page.
-I need to refresh the webpage to see the new message added to the list, and I don't want to have to refresh the webpage.

What I can't figure how to do:
-How to update the messages list on the page without refreshing the page. I think I just don't get the AJAX part..

index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        Message: <input type="text" id="message">
        <input type="button" id="message-submit" value="Envoyer">
        <input type="button" id="display" value="Afficher">

        <div id="output" align="center">    
        </div>    

        <script src="jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/comments.js"></script>
        <script src="js/showComments.js"></script>

    </body>  
</html>
```

comments.js (some Javascript and Json)

```
$('input#message-submit').on('click', function () {
    var message = $('input#message').val();
    if($.trim(message) != '') { 
            $.post('ajax/showComments.php', {message: message}, function(data) {        
            });
    }
});
```

showComments.js

```
$(function () 
{

    $.ajax({                                      
        url: 'ajax/showComments.php', 
        data: "", 
        dataType: 'json',  
        success: function(rows)        
            {
            for (var i in rows)
            {
            var row = rows[i];          
            var id = row[0];
            var message = row[1];
            var date = row[2];
            $('#output').append("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> message: </b>"+message+"<b> date: </b>"+date)
                      .append("<hr />");
            } 
            } 
            });
});
```

showComments.php (DB work)

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "root";

  $databaseName = "testAjax";
  $tableName = "messages";  


  $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);



  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName"); 


 $data = array();
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
    {
    $data[] = $row;
    }


echo json_encode( $data );   



if (isset($_POST['message']) === true && empty($_POST['message']) === false) {

    $query = mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO `testAjax`.`messages` (
        `message_id` ,
        `message` ,
        `date`
        )
        VALUES (
        NULL , '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['message']))."',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        );
    ");


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need to refresh the page, just make keep the method that inserts the new message in the database and if the insert is executed with success, return a response with the message and additional data ( if you need it ) to ajax and in the success response just get the content and append it to the current messages that are displayed to the page. Hope it makes logic to you

Comment: Yes it makes sense and it's exactly what I am trying to figure how to code. Like I said I don't have much experience with javascript and ajax so it's a bit confusing to me..

Comment: Sorry about that. You can try an example from here [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), from php you can return a flag variable with true or false for error, if error flag is false then take the content and append, if true, display an error.